# How do I open Mobile Sync?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am trying to look at old iCloud backups and I watched a couple of videos explaining how. I went to Finder / Go menu, then held the  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  button and Library apeared. I pressed it. I pressed Application Support. That's what they told me to do in the videos.

Now the problem is that I can't find Mobile Sync like it was on the video.

Comment: Did you also break your caps lock key???

Comment: iCloud doesn't backup to your Mac. Your iPhone backs up to that folder when you initiate it from iTunes. As it stands we really cannot tell quite what it is you are trying to achieve. At the moment, we just have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Which macOS version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud backups don't appear in the MobileSync folder. You have to back up with iTunes.